# Crash in Google Maps caused by a null pointer in android.widget.EdgeEffect.<init>

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I've been seeing a crash on the ZTE Z993 (Android 4.1.1) that occurs in apps that use a `MapView` or `SupportMapFragment` (e.g. Lyft, Yelp, Airbnb). It looks like the crash occurs in the initialization of `EdgeEffect` within a `ListView` that Google Maps uses. The link below points to a git repo that reproduces the crash. I've also included the stacktrace. Has anyone seen this? Can anyone suggest a fix? Thanks!

[github repo for a project that reproduces the crash](https://github.com/zumper/GoogleMapsTest)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.googlemapstest/com.test.googlemapstest.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4795)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
            at com.test.googlemapstest.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2044)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4795)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.EdgeEffect.<init>(EdgeEffect.java:153)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.setOverScrollMode(AbsListView.java:824)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3237)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3295)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:427)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.<init>(AdapterView.java:235)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:758)
            at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:141)
            at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:137)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.p.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.p.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.dd.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.el.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ab.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.aa.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
            at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:922)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1114)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1216)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2169)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
            at com.test.googlemapstest.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2044)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4795)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
```

Bug reported here:
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7915